# Could not calculate build plan error

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-kepler

```
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: 
    Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
```

I have tried all search results but didn't find the solution. Deleted the repository many times, still getting same error. Also I could not find my `settings.xml` file neither I am able to create my own. If someone can provide me the `settings.xml` file and suggest the required changes.

Comment: Your Maven installation is probably broken.  I suggest you reinstall Maven from scratch.

Comment: I assume based on that `or one of its dependencies could not be resolved` that you have not downloaded all required dependencies (firewall/proxy) issue or something else. Try to build from start via `mvn clean package` and beofore delete the local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` ...